# i am facing some issue while running logstash.conf file in my local

Tags: elastic-stack

[2021-03-08T09:26:49,386][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
at C_3a_.Users.kishorv.Downloads.logstash_minus_7_dot_11_dot_1.lib.bootstrap.environment.(C:\Users\kishorv\Downloads\logstash-7.11.1\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error message when trying to run Logstash in Windows Powershell, but the real message was further up in the output text - in my case it was because it could not create a directory.

The fix for this was to make sure I was running PowerShell as Administrator.